# Program for learning foreign words C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am in the process of writing a vocabulary program. C # Windows Form.

Description of the program operation:

- Use the buttons to select the location of text files with the words "PL" and "ENG". (two separate files)
- Click the start button to start the program
- the first word from the board appears in the label
- I'm translating the word into the textbox and the Messagebox "OK" or "WRONG" pops up

And here a problem arises. The program instead of every time I wait until I introduce a new word to the textbox, it loops, the questions in the label are changed and MessageBox displays.
How best to do this to make the program work correctly? `` `[

```
private void sprawdzButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BazaSlow.bazaPolskichSlowek = _fileReader.Read(adresPlikuPL);
        BazaSlow.bazaAngielskichSlowek = _fileReader.Read(adresPlikuANG);
        string odpowiedz = odpTextBox.Text;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < BazaSlow.bazaPolskichSlowek.Length)
        {
            trescSlowkaLabel.Text = BazaSlow.bazaPolskichSlowek[i];

            if (odpowiedz.Equals(BazaSlow.bazaAngielskichSlowek[i].ToLower()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ŹLE");
            }
            i++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger and single-step through the code and inspect the state and value of all involved variables/fields/collections/etc while stepping through the code. Setting some breakpoints will be valuable as well. ([Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger), [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/))

Comment: Well i already did it, and still can't find good solution..

Comment: I don't have idea for this.

Comment: Neither can we. The code in your question does not reveal anything obvious, nor is it a [mcve]. I suggest, you debug once more, but a bit more thoroughly this time. (The links i gave in my 1st comment might perhaps be helpful if you seek to improve your debugging skills)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will not quite work.
If you use WinForms then you can do it via events. I'll quickly use english variable names since I don't speak your language.

This could be one approach to do it: I used the "TextChanged" event from the textBox.

```
    string[] wordsLanguage1;
    string[] wordsLanguage2;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wordsLanguage1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("somePath1");
        wordsLanguage2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("somePath2");
    }

    private void ReportAndCheckInput(string input)
    {
        if (input.ToLower().Equals(wordsLanguage2[currentIndex].ToLower())) {
            //right translation
            currentIndex++;
            label1.Text = wordsLanguage1[currentIndex];
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            //wrong translation
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportAndCheckInput(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Now this approach uses the `TextChanged` event. So the `ReportAndCheckInput` method will be called on every text-change. That means that your Feedback would pop up on every keystroke which would not be nice. You could use any other event instead of `TextChanged`. For example a button click. Another solution would be to use a label for your feedback and not a message box. Then the user would never have to click anything but woudl instantly see whether or not he was correct.

Comment: Welcome. Please mark this as your answer if you think that it solved your problem so that future users can see that.